# Does order of the components in a set matter?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjrSh.png)$A=\{ a,b,c \}$
$B= \{a,c,d\}$

$A\times B=\{ (a,a),(a,c),(a,d),(b,a),(b,c),(b,d),(c,a),(c,c),(c,d)\}$
$B\times A= \{ (a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c),(d,a),(d,b),(d,c)\}$

i want to intersect this two sets.

$(A \times B) \cap (B \times A)=$ ???

my question is, is $(c,b)$ and $(b,c)$ the same thing?
because, if they are same I am going to have the different result in comparison to if they are not same.

If not why?

this is the original question. I am solving b.

Comment: Where do the $d$s come from?

Comment: They are not the same because (by definition) $A \times B$ is a set of _ordered_ pairs.

Comment: We use $\{a,b\}$ to mean an unordered set, $(a,b)$ to mean an ordered set (or tuple).  So, $\{a,b\} = \{b,a\}$ but $(a,b) \neq (b,a)$ (assuming $a \neq b$.)

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake in the second set.
now, that is fixed.

Comment: A good exercise is to show that $(A \times B) \cap (X \times Y) = (A \cap X) \times (B \cap Y)$.  This might streamline your question.

Comment: Your **question itself** is all over the place. Please consider cleaning your post up and focusing on a single issue at a time. Anyhow, $\{a,b\}=\{b,a\}$ but $(a,b)\neq(b,a)$; *sets* are distinct from *ordered pairs*.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same.

By definition, $$(a,b)=(c,d)\iff a=c \wedge b=d$$

and so $(a,b)\not=(b,a)$ for $a\not=b$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your title:  Do order of $\require{cancel}\bcancel{\text{compenents}}$ elements in a set matter?

No.  A set is an unordered collection of elements.  $\{fred,wilma,barney,betty\}=\{betty,wilma, fred,barney\}$ because order does not matter.

The answer to your body: is $(c,b)$ and $(b,c)$ the same thing?

No.  $A\times B$ is defined to be a set of *ordered* pairs.  $(c,b)$ is not an unordered set but is an *ordered* pair.  $(c,b) \ne (b,c)$.

Comment: after solving this I got,
{(a,a),(a,c),(c,c),(c,a)}

is this correct?

Comment: Yes,  If you check them off term by terms is what you would get.  Also common sense can tell us if $(x,y) \in A\times B$ and $(x,y) \in B\times A$ then $x,y $ are both in both $A$ and $B$ and as $a,c$ are the only elements in both $A$ and $B$ it makes sense that the terms would be the combinations of those.  Randall's comment above hints that you can formally prove that.  But I think developing a taste for the feel of these is equally important.